# Java: The operator - is undefined for the argument types double, double[]

Tags: java, arrays, methods, double

The error "the operator - is undefined for the argument types double[], double" keeps showing up in the following method and I can't figure out why or how to fix it.

```
   public static double inputstartX (double targetX[])throws IOException{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Please enter the horizontal starting point");
            while (true){
                try {
                    double x = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                    if ((targetX-x)<=500 && (targetX-x)>=50){
                        return x;
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("The starting point must be at a horizontal distance between 50 to 500 meters away from the target");
                        System.out.println("Please enter the horizontal starting point again");
                    }
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input, please try again");
                }
            }
```

Specifically at the line:
**"if ((targetX-x)<=500 && (targetX-x)>=50){"**

Comment: you are trying to subtract a number from an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to subtract from array, which is not a double.
Arrays store multiple values of the same type in itself.
You need to call one of them such as `targetX[0]` which will give the first value.

Or if you think the `[]` was an error just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

targetX is an array of doubles. Which means that you can not substract another double from it. You will first have to specify an element which is in the array.

Example:

```
targetX[0] -= x;
        ^
  index of element (in this case: 0)
```